# Why several Unicode symbols are not LC nor UC at the same time?

Tags: unicode

The following demo https://3v4l.org/8dl3G shows there are 31 Unicode symbols that neither LC nor UC, or more precisely lowercasing it produces a different symbol and uppercasing it produced a different symbol too at the same time.

I verified it using Javascript:

```
console.log(String.fromCharCode(453).toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0));
console.log(String.fromCharCode(453).toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0));
```

and it confirmed the demo findings above.

What is the reason, what does it solve?

Comment: Looks language specific: [Dž](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C5%BE). Particularly _"...when the letter is the initial of a capitalised word (like Džungla or Džemper, or personal names like Džemal or Džamonja), the ž is not uppercase. Only when the whole word is written in uppercase, is the Ž capitalised...The capitalized version of this letter ('Ǆ'), as a single character in Unicode"_

Comment: Congratulations, you discovered Title case. In Serbian, Dž is considered one letter, and it has three forms depending on casing context.